# Почему в окне префаба не видны объекты на сцене?

Tags: unity3d

В последнее время я пытаюсь разобраться как устроены префабы в unity. У меня есть префаб "Море". На нём висит скрипт "Button_script", в котором есть публичный GameObject Player_choice. При открытии префаба в окне иерархии закрывается сцена. При нажатии на кружочек рядом с Player_choice открывается окно, но там видны только префабы. Пожалуйста не надо предлагать использовать GameObject.find... Мне просто хочется знать, почему нельзя префабу вручную поставить значение объекта?! Или всё-таки можно?

[image: скрин]

[image: скрин]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В момент создания копии префаба этих объектов на сцене может и не быть. Поэтому мы и не можем указывать в префабах ссылки на них. И никто не гарантирует, что префаб заспавнят на этой же сцене. Если попытаться сохранить в префаб объект, у которого стоят такие ссылки, то они все превратятся в None (в коде будет null).

Ссылаться на объекты сцены могут только объекты на этой же сцене. Так что можно вытащить префаб на сцену и выбрать нужный объект с нее.

Comment: Спасибо, это полностью проясняет ситуацию

Answer (score 0):

Может быть я не правильно понял вопрос, но если вы хотите "спавнить" обьекты во время игры и назначать действия на кнопки, то вам нужен [AddListener()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Events.UnityEvent.AddListener.html).